# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'assertionClosure' on null object

Tags: java, api, rest, automation, rest-assured

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'assertionClosure' on null object

```java
RequestSpecification createOrderBaseReq = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
        .addHeader("Authorization", Token ).setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .build();
    
    
    
    CreateOrderRequestPojo  CreateOrderRequest = new CreateOrderRequestPojo();

    CreateOrderRequest.setCountry("India");
    CreateOrderRequest.setProductOrderedId(productid);
    
    List<CreateOrderRequestPojo>  CreateOrderRequestlist = new ArrayList<CreateOrderRequestPojo>();
    CreateOrderRequestlist.add(CreateOrderRequest);
    
    OrdersPojo orders = new  OrdersPojo();
    orders.setOrders(CreateOrderRequestlist);
    
    RequestSpecification createOrderReq = createOrderBaseReq.given().log().all().spec(createOrderBaseReq).body(orders);
    
    String CreateOrderResponce = createOrderReq.when().post("/api/ecom/order/create-order").then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
    
    
        System.out.println(CreateOrderResponce);
```

getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'assertionClosure' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.getProperty(NullCallSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoFieldSite.callGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoFieldSite.java:48)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1702)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:328)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.doInvokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1348)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1103)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:792)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1710)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.this$2$applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:328)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.doInvokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1348)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1103)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:792)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:176)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at Endtoendautomationproduct.EcommersceApiTest.main(EcommersceApiTest.java:96)
```

I was expecting an responce that it will add some product

Comment: Which is line 96 of your code?